# Android parse.com can`t upload file

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, upload

My app worked well half month ago, but now i have problem.
I can't upload image into parse.com in certain table. It's problem only on devices, on emulator app working well.
I`m trying this code (select image from gallery):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        String realPath;
        // SDK < API11
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(this, data.getData());

            // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(this, data.getData());

            // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4)
        else
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, data.getData());
        File file = new File(realPath);
        try {
            byte bytes[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            BufferedInputStream bf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            bf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            bf.close();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.setIMG)).setImageBitmap(bmp);
            pFile = new ParseFile("file", bytes);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After it, when user click on special button, execute this code:

```
void sendPost(String txt) throws ParseException {
    String parseUserId = getIntent().getExtras().getString(ObjConst.OBJECT_ID);
    ParseUser parseUser = null;
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryUser = ParseUser.getQuery();
    queryUser.whereEqualTo(ObjConst.OBJECT_ID, parseUserId);
    try {
        parseUser = queryUser.getFirst();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e("INTERNET", "Problem with internet connection or can`t find your accaunt.");
    }

    if (parseUser != null) {
        final ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject(ObjConst.POST);
        parseObject.put(ObjConst.POST_ANONIMOUS, checkBox.isChecked());
        parseObject.put(ObjConst.POST_AUTHOR, parseUser);
        parseObject.put(ObjConst.POST_TEXT, txt);
        final Context ctx = this;
        if (pFile != null) {
            parseObject.put(ObjConst.POST_PHOTO, pFile);
            Log.d("MY_TAG", "Start upload.");
            pFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.d("MY_TAG", "ParseException: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    Log.d("MY_TAG", "Start save ParseObject");
                    saveParseObject(parseObject, ctx);
                }
            }, new ProgressCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(Integer percentDone) {
                    Log.d("MY_TAG", percentDone+" %");
                }
            });
        } else saveParseObject(parseObject, ctx);
    }
}

void saveParseObject(ParseObject parseObject, final Context ctx) {
    Log.d("MY_TAG", "Start saveParseObject()");
    parseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            Log.d("MY_TAG", e.getMessage());
            Log.d("MY_TAG", "End. ParseObject saved. " + e.getMessage());

            if (e != null)
                Log.i("Write post.", "Can`t write post. Problem with internet connection.");
            else Toast.makeText(ctx,
                    "Отправлено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Output of the program:

```
01-04 21:46:02.376 7360-7360/com.appserv D/MY_TAG: Start upload.
01-04 21:46:02.433 7360-7360/com.appserv D/MY_TAG: 58 %
01-04 21:46:02.434 7360-7360/com.appserv D/MY_TAG: 100 %
01-04 21:46:13.615 7360-7360/com.appserv D/MY_TAG: 58 %
01-04 21:46:13.618 7360-7360/com.appserv D/MY_TAG: 100 %
01-04 21:46:25.941 7360-7360/com.appserv D/MY_TAG: 58 %
01-04 21:46:25.945 7360-7360/com.appserv D/MY_TAG: 100 %
01-04 21:46:40.553 7360-7360/com.appserv D/MY_TAG: 58 %
01-04 21:46:40.557 7360-7360/com.appserv D/MY_TAG: 100 %
01-04 21:46:59.725 7360-7360/com.appserv D/MY_TAG: 58 %
01-04 21:46:59.730 7360-7360/com.appserv D/MY_TAG: 100 %
01-04 21:47:09.754 7360-7360/com.appserv D/MY_TAG: ParseException: i/o failure
01-04 21:47:09.754 7360-7360/com.appserv D/MY_TAG: Start save ParseObject
01-04 21:47:09.754 7360-7360/com.appserv D/MY_TAG: Start saveParseObject()
```

What is it?)

Comment: I would add some more log statements.  You don't have any indication of whether the file object is null, or the file save fails, or what.

Comment: @nasch , I add logs in my question.
This file is not null, because I set this image into ImageView and it correct displayed.

Comment: I don't mean to paste irrelevant stuff from logcat, I mean add some debugging statements to your code so you can tell what's happening.  Or step through it in a debugger.

Comment: @nasch , I`m sorry.  I rewrote the second code. Check it, please. And I wrote output of my app.

Comment: Only problem I'm seeing is you're not checking the `ParseException` from the file save.  If that's not null then you're getting an exception there.  Check for that and maybe that will give you more info.

Comment: @nasch , I've updated the code. And now have new string in output:
01-04 21:47:09.754 7360-7360/com.appserv D/MY_TAG: ParseException: i/o failure

Comment: No idea what would cause that, I'd take to google and/or SO and see if you can find anything about that error message saving a parse file.

Answer (score 0):

try on this way any type of image its successfully uploaded in parse database.

```
String first = "your image Path";
    final ParseFile Parseimagecam1;
    int targetW = 450;
    int targetH = 800;
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(first, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;
    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the
    // View

    // imgHome.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor << 1;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(first, bmOptions);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] img1 = stream.toByteArray();
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    Parseimagecam1 = new ParseFile("IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg", img1);
    Parseimagecam1.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                // success
                // here call your new method for upload image like
                uploadImage(Parseimagecam1);
            } else {
                // error
            }

        }
    });
}

protected void uploadImage(ParseFile parseimagecam1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject(ObjConst.POST);
    parseObject.put("keyName", parseimagecam1);
    parseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                // success check your data base
            } else {
                // fail
            }

        }
    });
}
```

it's completed work for me .
i have uploaded image up to 6 in parse table.

Comment: It does not work for me.
But, if I take image from package drawable: Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeRecource(getRecource(), R.drawable.smallimg);, where smallimg- very small image, my app work very well, this image upload into server.